# Reduce number of votes required to close duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, flagging, vote-to-close, exact-duplicates

Probably, due to the Expatriates specifics, some topics (Blue card, residence permits) regularly suffer from duplicate questions. Only for Germany-related questions, I have marked almost 30 duplicates: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/13223/andrey-sapegin?tab=votes

However, most of them are still not closed, since it is required to have 5 votes in order to close the question.

Is there a way to fix this and reduce the number of required votes to 2-3 in order to clean up Expatriates from duplicates?

Comment: I recommend that you create a SEDE query to figure out how many people actually participate in the review queues, and, possibly, create a meta post encouraging people to do a bit more reviewing. (We had a similar discussion on [Literature SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1288/2191), where you can find links to example queries.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is something configurable. As we're a beta site however the limits to users to allow close votes are lower anyway, and I'm usually acting on flags in the system as well

Comment: As far as I know, it can be "configured" by SO, but my understanding is that it would apply to all close reasons and to reopen votes alike, i.e. the number of votes cannot be configured separately for different close reasons or reopen votes. (That's what I found when we discussed this on [Literature SE](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1288/2191).)